# where log file found for devops analytics found

Tags: powerbi, odata, azure-pipelines, analytics

I am running the below query.  One of the columns returned is "TaskLogPath".  I would like to use this column to link the logs to the activities but have not been able to figure out what the possible link/url is to retrieve.

[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRunActivityResults?%24select=PipelineRunId%2CPipelineSK%2CActivityCompletedDate%2CTaskDisplayName%2CTaskLogPath%2CTaskOutcome%2CActivityDurationSeconds+&%24expand=PipelineJob&%24apply=filter%28PipelineRunCompletedOn%2FDate+ge+2021-01-17%29"](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRunActivityResults?%24select=PipelineRunId%2CPipelineSK%2CActivityCompletedDate%2CTaskDisplayName%2CTaskLogPath%2CTaskOutcome%2CActivityDurationSeconds+&%24expand=PipelineJob&%24apply=filter%28PipelineRunCompletedOn%2FDate+ge+2021-01-17%29%22), null, [Implementation="2.0"])

Does anybody know where these log files are located (ie: devops agent or other place).  I tried to get them using the below which doesn't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

1. Capture the value of `TaskLogPath`. Example `logs/{timelineRecordId}`
2. Make a reset api call to the builds timeline endpoint `/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildRunId}/timeline`
3. Match the `timelineRecordId` to the value of `.records[].id` from timeline endpoint
4. That will give you thje timeline record payload which has the `.log.url`

Answer (score 0):

In the individual pipeline hit the three dots in the top right and select Download Logs.  This will download a zip file of all the associated information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I may not have asked my question correctly.  I want to know how to utilise the log link returned by the analytics service so that I can use in my power bi report.  I can get all the logs using the second link in my query but I would like to be able show the logs against each task.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Build [Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Rest api to retrieve the task logs against each task.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=6.0
```

You can get the details of each task, with its associated log path. See below:

[image]

Comment: Yes I have tried that... but that doesn't allow me to match these logs against each task.  Its a list of the logs without (as far as I can tell ) specific relationship to each task.  The only way I could use is to try and use the order of each to match up to a task.

Comment: @kez. Above TimeIine api returns the details of each task with its specific log details in the `log` properties.  I guess what you tried is Build log get rest api, not the above timeline get api.

Comment: @Kez Please try calling url `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=6.0`